# Setting up continuous deployment using manual steps in Azure Web App Service / GitLab fails

Tags: gitlab, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-deployment

I want to set up a CD for my Azure Web App Service, I'm using a **private** GitLab Repository. Why is the "Sync" Button not clickable?

1. Fetched SSH from Web App Service with

> https://website.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1

2. Added SSH to GitLab (Settings > Repository > Deploy Keys)
3. Added Deployment Settings in my Azure Web App Service (Deployment Center) as followed:

[image: Deployment Settings in my Azure Web App Service (Deployment Center)]

Steps are from [kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#setting-up-continuous-deployment-using-manual-steps) Documentation. As said [here](https://rainstormtech.com/configuring-cicd-from-gitlab-to-an-azure-web-app) the Sync Button should work now but it doesnt. Any ideas for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation says](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#create-an-azure-web-app-and-enable-source-control-with-an-external-repository):

> Use your repo's URL when setting this up. This will allow the '`sync`' button in the portal to work.
>
> Note: this may not work with private GitHub repos ([see issue 2464](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2464)). In that case, you may need to set it up as Local Git instead.

Note that for a SSH URL (`git@gitlab.xxx.git`), you do not use username/password usually. Try and use an HTTPS URL instead.